# GSON Parse string returns null?

Tags: java, json, parsing

For some reason I am having issues with `GSON` parsing data from `JSON_STRING`. When I attempt to parse I am returned with null. Can you please help me with the code below and let me know where I went wrong?  My objective is to ultimately parse JSON feed from url, but I figured to hard code the string for testing purpose.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ReadJson {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String JSON_STRING = 
            "{\"data\":[{\"NAME\":\"Brandy\",\"LOCATION\":\"Redding, CA\"},
                        {\"NAME\":\"Jacob\",\"LOCATION\":\"Redding, CA\"},
                        {\"NAME\":\"Tatiana\",\"LOCATION\":\"Wonderland\"},
                        {\"NAME\":\"Tedo\",\"LOCATION\":\"Cottonwood\"}]}";
        DataJSON data2 = new Gson().fromJson(JSON_STRING, DataJSON.class);
        System.out.println(data2);

    }
}

class DataJSON {
    public String NAME;
    public String LOCATION;
    public String getName() { return NAME; }
    public String getLocation() { return LOCATION;}
    public void setName(String NAME) { this.NAME = NAME; }
    public void setLoction(String LOCATION) { this.LOCATION = LOCATION; }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("NAME:%s,LOCATION:%s", NAME, LOCATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot directly print out data2 I guess. have you debugged the project and watched data2's values?

Comment: It seems he has overidden `toString()` in `DataJSON` class !!!

Comment: and yes you should put @Override to top of toString.

Comment: I am new to posting questions on Stackoverflow. My question was -1, what could I have done to ask in a more appropriate manor?

Answer (score 0):

You have a list in your json and so you need to wrap DataJSON inside a list. Something like this.

```
class DataJSONWrapper {
    public List<DataJSON> list = new ArrayList<DataJSON>();
    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: i am not the one giving downvote, but please provide the class (at least attributes) for the asker's case.

Comment: This is the class. It's using the class provided by the asker.

Comment: ah sorry then, i'm not familiar with the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an object with a single field (`data`) that contains an array of objects. You have a class that represents the objects *inside the array* (`DataJSON`)

Your POJO that Gson will deserialize to needs to be:

```
class MyData {
    List<DataJSON> data;
}
```

If you then do:

```
MyData md = gson.fromJson(JSON_STRING, MyData.class);
```

It will deserialize properly.